# C# .NET API Validate Query Parameters Are on Model

Tags: c#, .net, api, validation

I have a C# .NET API that I am working on and I am hoping to validate that query parameters used in the URL are valid properties on the model I have.

I have a model that I use to define valid query parameters and take them in as below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("/[controller]/getData")]
public IActionResult GetData([FromQuery] ParameterModel params)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Say I have a property named `Param1` on that model. If somebody passes that in from the URL string it works correctly and maps the data to the property. However if there is a typo like `Parm1` that value is simply ignored.

I would like to return a bad request when a misnamed parameter is passed in like that so it is clear it is a bad parameter instead of simply ignoring it.

Is there a built in validation with .NET that can do this? If not I plan to write some code to handle it but would prefer to do it with out of the box options from .NET if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand your question, you want to know if your Model is valid. The correct way to do that is using:

```
ModelState.IsValid
```

My own implementation of your request would be the following:

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("/[controller]/getData")]
public IActionResult GetData([FromQuery] ParameterModel params)
{
    //Check if current modelstate is valid, else return bad request
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
       return BadRequest(ModelState);
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It doesn't look like this does what I'm hoping for. For instance if the property on the model is named `Param1`, the URL `/controller/method?param1=123` and `/controller/method?badparam=123` both return true for `ModelState.IsValid`. I would like that second request to be flagged since there is no `BadParam` property on the model.

Comment: @DeveloperGuy is param1 nullable? You can also try to add the [Required] attribute to param1

Comment: Param1 is nullable and an optional parameter in this case. What I would like to prevent is somebody sending in a parameter that does not exist on the model, because they would still get data back since the parameter is ignored.

Comment: What you could do is getting the query parameters from this.ActionContext.Request.RequestUri
Then you can compare that to the variables in your model, by getting all the variable names in your model, then throw a exception if there are more parameters then needed.

I do not recommend this aproach, because it is normal for HttpRequests to allow all query parameters, and only take the ones needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't able to find anything built in with C#/.NET to do this, I ended up writing a method to check the parameters from the request against a model and use that for the validation:

```
public bool AreQueryParametersValid(ParameterModel parameters, HttpRequest request)
{
    var paramProperties = parameters.GetType().GetProperties();
    var validParams = new List<string>();

    foreach (var parameter in paramProperties)
    {
        validParams.Add(parameter.Name.ToLower());
    }

    foreach (var queryParam in request.Query.Keys)
    {
        if (!validParams.Contains(queryParam.ToLower()))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```